# How to load and visualize an R data frame into Shiny app

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I would like to load and visualize an already saved R data frame from my local PC (named dfFinal.Rda) into a Shiny app. I know that the following code works for sure, when loading and visualizing a prebuilt dataset from R (mtcars):

**ui.r file:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
h2("MT Cars data frame"),
DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)
```

**server.r file:**

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
mtcars
})
}
```

What piece of code do i have to include for loading the **dfFinal.Rda** data frame that i have saved in my PC, in order to visualize it into Shiny, instead of the **mtcars** data frame that is currently being shown?

Comment: You could load the data frame in the server function and assign it to a variable: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html. Then replace `mtcars` with that variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You can import it in your server file as below. It would be the best practices to create a data folder in your shiny app directory and put your file there.

```
server.r file:

library(shiny)

###
data <- readRDS("your path")
##
server <- function(input, output) {
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
data
})
}
```

Comment: it works! I included the file into the app folder and modified the path accordingly. Thank you.